# MySql #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now when calling a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have successfully created a stored procedure in my mySql and when I tried to run it, but it returns

> Error
> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
> SQL query: Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

I don't know if how can I resolve this one for my searches didn't give me any luck. I call my stored procedure this way:

```
call getReport('2018-09-27','2018-09-27');
```

The code:

```
BEGIN 

SET @query := select * from history where date(`history`.`execDate`) between startDate and endDate;

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;

END
```

My stored procedure requires two date parameters. There are times that my stored procedure works without any error, and I'm not touching anything on its configurations. My query also works on my colleague's PC and I think the problem is already on my end and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please add your Stored procedure code also ot the question

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya see updates.

Comment: Does someone have faced and resolved this kind of problem? I really need your help on this, please.

Comment: Why are you using `Concat` function. I dont see any second string, to which you are concatenating the data

Comment: That set statement is not valid and throws a 1064 error in mysql. You should be passing a string to @query. And any reason why you are not deallocating the prepared statement?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Forgot to remove it.

Comment: @P.Salmon How can I deallocate it?

Comment: You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 1):

- `SET` statement syntax is wrong. You set the variable using `=` not `:=`
- To prepare the complete query string, you are not using [Concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function properly. `CONCAT` function takes strings to concatenate as different parameters.
- Also, after executing the Prepared statement, you should [Deallocate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/deallocate-prepare.html) it.

Try the following:

```
BEGIN 

SET @query = CONCAT('select * from history where date(`history`.`execDate`) between ', 
                    startDate, 
                    ' and ', 
                    endDate);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```